# Reconstructing the virtual memory usage of a crashed java process

Tags: java, linux, memory-leaks, virtual-memory, segmentation-fault

I have the hs_err_pid of a long running java process that has received a SIGSEGV. In [C.6 System Section](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/felog-138657.html) I can get a rough approximation of the free memory on the system from (MemFree + Buffers + Cached) / MemTotal, but I would like to find out exactly how much memory this process was addressing at the time of the crash, is this captured in this file? There doesn't appear to be any segment size reported in `C.5.5 Memory Map`, for example.

For context, I know of a situation that causes the processes `VIRT` memory column in `top` to constantly increase, and I would like to reconstruct whether this leak was present at the time of the crash. The information in `C.5.4 Heap Summary` is not useful as there is no leak in the heap memory.